# Google Sign-In for Android with a backend server

Tags: android, android-sdk, google-api

Мне нужно установить в моем приложении регистрацию с помощью гугла. Первое что я сделал это прочитал [документацию](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating), после чего выполнив всё из перечисленного раза 4, я никак не могу добиться получения успешного ответа от *GoogleSignInResult*. Код брал из [примера](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java#L51-L55), и он работает при простом запросе, таком как `.requestEmail()`, но при `.requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))` не работает. Хочу уточнить! При создании *Credential* я использовал **не существующий адрес, то есть  сервера еще нет!** Может ли быть это от того, что сервера нет? Я думал, что сначала токен генерируется на основе *server_client_id*, а только потом происходит связь с сервером. И, если можно, дайте пожалуйста ссылку на хорошую статью по *OAuth*. Я находил в оригинале, но мне пока тяжело прочитать всё в оригинале, спасибо.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/115163/

Comment: Спасибо, эта статья прояснила для меня данный нюанс, а именно то, что без рабочего сервера успешный ответ не получить.

Comment: https://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/android-oauth2-webview.html

Comment: Не, вот, показательней. Сопоставьте `redirectUri = "your://redirecturi";` и `<data android:host="redirecturi" android:scheme="your" />` https://futurestud.io/tutorials/oauth-2-on-android-with-retrofit

Answer (score 0):

Я написал небольшую библиотеку для такого [SocialAuth](https://github.com/pavel163/SocialAuth). Там есть подробная инструкция и пример

Comment: Я обязательно посмотрю ваши идеи. Спасибо